# MS Access Combine tables with like fields

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to get a combined result of Costs and Payments sorted by date. This is the query I'm trying:

```
SELECT ClientID, TheDate, Payment, Cost
FROM
(
  SELECT PaymentDate AS TheDate, Amount AS Payment, ClientID
  FROM Payment
  UNION ALL
  SELECT BookedDate AS TheDate, Cost, ClientID
  FROM [All Bookings Query]
)
ORDER BY TheDate DESC;
```

It almost works... however, a box pops up for me to enter a value for "Payment" (like the field doesn't exist). If I leave that blank and hit OK, I get a result set with the "Payment" column totally blank, and the "Cost" column containing the amounts from both tables. The field names I'm using are 100% correct.

I think the problem is that UNION is trying to squash both tables into a result with 3 columns, and I am trying to select 4. I've never done a query quite like this before so I don't know how to get around that.

What I want is for Payments and Costs to be in separate columns. What is wrong with my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have 4 columns in each of the sub-queries, putting 0 into the cost column for payments and 0 into the payments column for bookings.

```
SELECT ClientID, TheDate, Payment, Cost
FROM
(
  SELECT PaymentDate AS TheDate, Amount AS Payment, 0 AS Cost, ClientID
  FROM Payment
  UNION ALL
  SELECT BookedDate AS TheDate, 0 As Payment, Cost, ClientID
  FROM [All Bookings Query]
)
ORDER BY TheDate DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks! I also discovered Access needs the order of fields in SELECT to match in all the queries.